# AndroidPlot: Can I set the size of my graph area in my XML rather than Java

Tags: android, androidplot

I use the following code to set the size of my graph area. I have done some searching but I haven't found a way to add this in the XML.

```
    // Set size of graph area (not plot area)
    final Size sm = new Size(900, SizeLayoutType.ABSOLUTE, 900, SizeLayoutType.ABSOLUTE);
    myPositionLines.getGraphWidget().setSize(sm);
```

How can I do this in the XML file as per the legend i.e. something like this:

`ap:legendHeight="40dp"`

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(Updated) As of Androidplot v0.9.7 there are now styleable attrs for controlling the size and positioning of the graph widget from XML.

Keep in mind though that because the graph is a widget component, the sizing / positioning conventions follow those of all other Androidplot widgets.  Check out the "x/y positioning widgets" and "sizing widgets" sections of [this doc](http://androidplot.com/docs/styling-your-plot/) for info on how that works.

Here are the xml attrs currently available:

```
<attr name="graphHeightSizeLayoutType"/>
<attr name="graphWidthSizeLayoutType"/>
<attr name="graphHeight" format="dimension|float|integer"/>
<attr name="graphWidth" format="dimension|float|integer"/>
<attr name="graphLayoutStyleX"/>
<attr name="graphLayoutStyleY"/>
<attr name="graphPositionX" format="dimension|float|integer"/>
<attr name="graphPositionY" format="dimension|float|integer"/>
<attr name="graphAnchorPosition"/>
```

So for example, adding the following to your plot's xml element would give your graph a width of 300dp:

```
ap:graphWidthSizeLayoutType="absolute"
ap:graphWidth="300dp"
```

Comment: Great thanks Nick. I will give this a go. I wanted something like this so I could have this code in the XML, so that I can follow Android's way of catering for different screen sizes!

Comment: I have just tried this with:
            ap:graphHeightSizeLayoutType="absolute"
            ap:graphHeight="300dp"
            ap:graphWidthSizeLayoutType="absolute"
            ap:graphWidth="300dp"
But it does not seem to work. The width seems to work but the height doesn't.

Comment: Confirmed - there's a bug in how the style is applied.  0.9.8 contains the fix and will be available no later than 5/6/2016.

Comment: ^ 0.9.8 is now available.

Comment: Thanks Nick. Initial testing showing it is working fine! Appreciated.

Comment: I am unable to do styling using xml cmd ap:graphWidthSizeLayoutType="absolute"
ap:graphWidth="300dp". I used com.androidplot:androidplot-core:0.9.8 library